# While inside another while

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display data from two different Mysql tables in the same html table. Do do that I have put a while loop inside another while loop. The problem is that in the table the data of the second loop is displayed only on the first raw of the html table. I really don't know what is wrong. Thanks for your help.

```
    <?php
    while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){


echo '<td>';
echo '<a href="linkto.php?data='.ucfirst($results['song_name']).'" class="iframe"><img src="icons/1384070574_95.png"> ';
echo '<a href="'.ucfirst($results['song_name']).'" class="clapping">';
echo  '<img src="icons/Hand-icon.png" id="songs'.$pictureid.'" onClick="action(\'songs'.$pictureid.'\')"/></a>';
echo '</td>'; 
echo '</tr>';
if (isset($userid)){

echo '<td>
        <div id="cssmenu">                              
                <ul>
                li class="has-sub><a href="#"><span><img src="icons/1384074758_document_music_add.png"></span></a>
                <ul>
                <li class="has-sub"><a href="#" class="newplaylist"><span>Create a Playlist</span></a></li>';      

            while($playlist = mysql_fetch_array($raw_playlist)){

                echo'<li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>'.ucfirst($playlist['title']).'</span></a></li>';

                }
echo'</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>                  
</td>';
                     } 
echo' </tr>
                ';
$pictureid = $pictureid + 1;
$songid= $songid + 1;
                   }
echo '</tbody>';

    ?>
```

Comment: FYI: $raw_playlist is not a query inside your loop

Comment: put $raw_playlist query inside your if condition & compare $userid or whatever you want accordingly....

Comment: Hi dev, do you mean the full Mysql query ?

Comment: ya...mysql_query() of $raw_playlist, put it in if condition before second while loop starts

Comment: and do not use mysql_*. read the red panel : [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: Thanks for you answers guys, isn't putting the mysql query in the if condition going to increase the requests between the server and the database as it will be called each time the first while is fetching ?

Comment: @cdxv5 Yes, it is. If possible, get all your data with a single query right at the start. Unless you're saying the data in `$raw_playlist` isn't related to `$raw_results`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you may have a problem with your nested data depending on what you're trying to show.

However, your HTML is a mess, missing some opening and closing tags, which may mean that some data is being sent to the browser but not being displayed. Have you looked at the source of the page in the browser to check the data is not there? Until you do, we cannot be sure whether the missing data is an HTML, SQL or PHP error.

You should try to limit the amount of HTML that you `echo` from PHP  for this reason, and I've tidied it up a bit and added missing tags below. See if that helps at all.

```
<?php while ($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)) : ?>
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="linkto.php?data=<?php echo ucfirst($results['song_name']); ?>" class="iframe"><img src="icons/1384070574_95.png"></a>
    <a href="<?php echo ucfirst($results['song_name']); ?>" class="clapping"><img src="icons/Hand-icon.png" id="songs<?php echo $pictureid; ?>" onClick="action('songs<?php echo $pictureid; ?>')" /></a>
  </td>
</tr>
<?php if (isset($userid)) : ?>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div id="cssmenu">                              
      <ul>
        <li class="has-sub><a href="#"><span><img src="icons/1384074758_document_music_add.png"></span></a>
          <ul>
            <li class="has-sub"><a href="#" class="newplaylist"><span>Create a Playlist</span></a></li>
<?php while ($playlist = mysql_fetch_array($raw_playlist)) : ?>
            <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span><?php echo ucfirst($playlist['title']); ?></span></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>                  
  </td>
<?php endif; ?> 
</tr>
<?php 
$pictureid++;
$songid++;
endwhile;
```